# Java - Add an instance of an abstract class in another instance

Tags: java, abstract

I have this piece of code :

```
public class Profile extends Container{
    public Profile(String value) {
        Container profilo_1 =new Container();
        Container profilo_2 =new Container();

        // (1) THIS ADD A BUTTON TO THE MAIN CLASS
        this.createButton().setLabel("Modifica Profilo");

        // (2) NOW I NEED TO ADD A BUTTON INTO THE INSTANCE OF profilo_2 BUT IT FAILS
        profilo_2.add(this.createButton());

        this.add(profilo_1);
        this.add(profilo_2);        
    }
}
```

the point (2) fails, because it said that im about to adding a child to this container, but it is owner already by a container...

In fact, if i do this :

```
ILabel label=new ILabel();
profilo_2.add(label);
```

it said to me that ILabel() is abract and cannot be instantiated!

How can I fix it? Cheers to everybody :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing wildly, since this depends on your code... Try this (moreless what Piotr said)

`profilo_2.add(profilo_2.createButton());`

Comment: Do you get an exception or does it simply not work? By the way, what framework are you using? I am guessing it is some UI framework? In that case, we can probably help you if you tell us which one.

Comment: i resolved :) With this profilo_2.createButton().setLabel("EDIT"); it works!! Just i call directly the instance of the container. Thanks, and yes it is a UI Framework :) p.s. as info, how can i "bold" my text in this stackoverflow comment box? I don't know the bbcode hehe

Comment: But now (for example) if i need to access to methods of that object (the Button created into profilo_2 when i call profilo_2.createButton()) how can I do it?

Comment: Button b = profilo_2.createButton(); b.setLabel("EDIT"); b.setXYZ(); and so on. The class name Button depends on what createButton() returns.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to

```
Button button2 = this.createButton();
button2.setLabel("EDIT");
profilo_2.add(button2);
```

By the way this has nothing to do with abstract classes, from what I see

**EDIT**: Though you say that #1 "adds a button to the main class", so does that mean that createButton() does this.add(button) ? If so then you should probably change that function so that isn't done every time you create a button.

Comment: yes if i do this.createButton(); it the same of this.add(button);

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that when you create a button with "this.createButton", that button has its parent set to "this" (in this context), and when you try to add it to profilo_2, it throws an error. Instead you should createButton on profilo_2 directly, then the parent will be the correct one (and perhaps you won´t have to add() it either?)

Comment: yes but how can i do it? See the topic, i edited it with more further info!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `setLabel()` returns something which cannot be passed to `Container::add(..)`. Please provide your code for `Container`